# Simple jquery plugin that quick looks information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any good JavaScript/jQuery plug-in that will 'quicklook' an information on click?

I want it simple so when you click the quick view link it just displays it as a modal form

Ideally it would be set up by just giving said links a class and the JavaScript/jQuery does the rest.

Similar to the (http://us.norton.com/downloads/) quick view button.

Comment: I think you're looking for Tooltip plugins - try googling a bit, there are *PLENTY*.

Comment: no not a tooltip plugin per say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[qtip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip) might come in handy too

Answer (score 0):

Norton is using colorbox i think.. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/
colorbox is a jQuery lightbox.. you can customize it using CSS.. it can handel inline content as well as fetch data by making an ajax call

Comment: Link-only answer - please provide context.

Comment: ok this was pretty helpful too. actually what I needed at first but I figured the second one was cool too